# Dividir frase con símbolo concreto en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Necesito dividir una frase con un símbolo concreto '/'.

Tengo hecho lo siguiente pero me divide cada palabra con una ',' y lo que quiero es que lo divida con '/'.

```js
var frase = "Esto es una frase";
var resultado = frase.split(" ");

document.write(resultado);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unes el array creado por `split` con `join`

```js
var frase = "Esto es una frase";
var resultado = frase.split(" ");


document.write(resultado.join("/"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Realmente [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/split) lo que hace es crear un array de cadenas basado en el separador que le indiques:

> El método `split()` divide un objeto de tipo String en un array
>   (vector) de cadenas mediante la separación de la cadena en subcadenas.

Cuando lo muestras, no es que te muestre tu cadena separada por comas como crees, sino que muestra los diferentes elementos del array que se ha creado, cada elemento separado por una coma.

Si se trata de *reemplazar*  los espacios por `/`, puedes usar [**`replace`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace):

> El método `replace()` halla un emparejamiento entre una expresión
>   regular y una cadena, y reemplaza la subcadena emparejada con una
>   nueva subcadena.

- `/ /g` indica que quieres capturar los espacios en blanco
- `"/"` es el caracter de reemplazo

```js
var frase = "Esto es una frase";
var resultado = frase.replace(/ /g, "/");
document.write(resultado);
```